# calling WEKA Ridor classifier from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, weka, classification

I can call J48 from MATLAB with no problem. But when I try the same with Ridor I'm getting fault code

> > classifier = weka.classifiers.trees.J48();

object classifier is created

> > c=weka.classifiers.rules.Ridor();
> >     ??? Undefined variable "weka" or class
> >     "weka.classifiers.rules.Ridor".

Any idea why ??

Krzysztof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [Using Java Libraries from MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f44062.html) help. My guess is that the required Java classes aren't on the path.

Comment: If they would not be on the path 1st example would not work I think.

Comment: In that case, are you sure that it contains the `weka.classifiers.rules.Ridor` class?

Comment: yes, Ridor works from WEKA GUI, I copied weka.classifiers.rules.Ridor class path from WEKA explorer window, it also matches specification. If you are user of MATLAB and WEKA just try...

Comment: I have similar problem with calling SMOTE

>> filter = weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToNominal();
>>

It works OK - MATLAB object is created but

>> filter = weka.filters.supervised.instance.SMOTE();
??? Undefined variable "weka" or class
"weka.filters.supervised.instance.SMOTE".

is not working. So what it is ???

Comment: OK I found the reason. Additional path must be defined for each package jar file. J48 is included in weka.jar but others no. For win7 the are in users/wekafiles directory

Comment: So the required Java classes weren't on the path, then.